# function with result TStringlist, best practice?

Tags: delphi

I would like to make a effective coding of this problem

```
function ADOConnectionWillExecute( Connection: TADOConnection; var CommandText:      
WideString;
 var CursorType: TCursorType; var LockType: TADOLockType;
 var CommandType: TCommandType; var ExecuteOptions: TExecuteOptions;
 var EventStatus: TEventStatus; const Command: _Command;
 const Recordset: _Recordset) : TStringlist ;

 begin

  result.AddStrings(
  CommandText,
  'Before '+GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCommandType),Integer(CommandType)),
   GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TEventStatus),Integer(EventStatus)),
   GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCursorType),Integer(CursorType)),
   GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TADOLockType),Integer(LockType)), 0);
  end;
```

In the original code source from the internet  all data are written into a GUI element, accepting strings and integer values, see [Build your own profiler using ADO](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/build-your-own-profiler-using-ado/)
.
My result.addstring does not work,  wont do any type conversions to eg. default string and also use result.add(...) statement

What will be the most effective way to handle this data without much extra coding?

Comment: What is the question? Obviously your code is broken because you don't instantiate the result variable. Why are you passing so many var parameters? Why are you using WideString? Old version of Delphi?

Comment: On a sidenote: who is responsible for creating and freeing TStringList?

Comment: @David It's blindly copied from the `TADOConnection.OnWillExecute` event signature shown in the mentioned blog article.

Comment: I only need help on the simple transfer of the data :  like this idea ( but not working)       begin
 
  result.commatext :=
 
    CommandText,
 
    'Before ' + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCommandType), integer(CommandType)),
 
    GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TEventStatus),integer(EventStatus)),
 
    GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCursorType), integer(CursorType)),
 
    GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TADOLockType), integer(LockType)),
 
    '0');
 
end

Comment: @Franz If you need help ask a question. But make sure it's well written. Or are the asker and are operating multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3):

This is Delphi 101. You have to create an instance of a class before you can use it, and your code doesn't do so.

You need to create `Result` before you can access it.

```
Result := TStringList.Create;
Result.AddStrings(....);
```

When returning an object instance from a function, you need to keep in mind that it is the responsibility of the calling code to free it afterward, so make sure you protect that code with `try..finally` to make sure that happens to avoid memory leaks.

Saying "does not work" is totally meaningless, unless you explain what "does not work" means. Please remember when asking questions here that we can't see your screen or read your mind, so you need to be specific when you write your questions. If you say "does not work", explain what you mean by that phrase. If you say "I get an error", describe the error and provide the **exact** error message (if any) you're getting, including any memory addresses or error codes. You have that information right in front of you, clearly, or you wouldn't know things weren't working or that you were getting an error. There's absolutely no reason to not provide those details in your question.

Comment: This is all true but it would seem that the bigger problem is that the method is an event handler that does not return a value. So this method can never be called by the framework.

Comment: There is no once again. There is just this question. What you say in your answer is accurate.

Comment: I consider it bad form to create and return objects, especially TSTringLists, because many API users will not think about freeing things that they return.  The more simple idiom would be to pass in a `TStrings` typed parameter.

Comment: @Warren: So do I, but that's not what the question asked.

Comment: When a user who doesn't know how to create an object returns an object, it's definitely answering the question to say, yeah, you're leaking that, you realize.

Comment: @WarrenP: I'm pretty sure I did that, in the paragraph right below the code block. What part of it beginning with "When returning an object instance" and ending with "to avoid memory leaks" wasn't clear to you? :-)

Comment: @David: First, the comment was based on Warren's immediately preceeding comment, which says we should say "yeah, you're leaking that, you realize". I was pointing out that I **did indeed say just that**. Second, you did notice the **:-)**, right?

Comment: Well, good point. And with our lovely discussion, I think this is as good as it gets.